# The variable optarg of the function getopt()

Tags: c, getopt

I've read through the [documentation for the function `getopt()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/optarg), but I do not find the explanations clear, especially with regards to the variable `optarg`. I cannot find any other sources that explicitly and clearly explain general information about `optarg`. My questions are as follows:

- What is `optarg`?
- How does `optarg` get its value?
- The documentation mentions something about colons changing the value of `optarg`; how does this work?

The documentation has examples of how to use `optarg`, but I am more so interested in clear and elaborate explanations of the variable itself.

Comment: Go back to that manpage, read the bit that says _"optstring is a string containing the legitimate option characters. If such a character is followed by a colon, the option requires an argument, so getopt() places a pointer to the following text in the same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element, in optarg."_ -- then read it again and again until it sinks in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/optarg) says, (*emphasis mine*)

> *optstring* is a string containing the legitimate option characters. If such a character is followed by a colon, the option requires an argument, so `getopt()` places **a pointer to the following text in the same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element, in `optarg`**. Two colons mean an option takes an optional arg; if there is text in the current argv-element (i.e., in the same word as the option name itself, for example, "-oarg"), then it is returned in optarg, otherwise optarg is set to zero. [...]

and the given code snippet below shows the usage.

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "nt:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
    case 'n':
        flags = 1;
        break;
    case 't':
        nsecs = atoi(optarg);
        tfnd = 1;
        break;
    default: /* '?' */
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-t nsecs] [-n] name\n",
                argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

To elaborate, by seeing the syntax `"nt:"` we can understand that the option `n` does not need any argument but option `t` will have a following argument to it. So, when the option `t` is found, the corresponding argument is stored into `optarg` and can be retrieved by accessing `optarg`.

So, basically, `getopt()` will return the *option* and `optarg` will return the *supplied argument* for that option, if any.

In case the binary is run like `./a.out -t 30`, then when `getopt()` returns `t`, `optarg` will be holding a pointer to a *string* containing `30` (not an `int`, mind it).